# Problem in displaying NSMutableArray data in the Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

HI, i am new to the iphone programming, i am using XML Parser to receive the data, i am storing the data in the NSMutable Array. (i can see the data in console using NSLog) I cant display the data in the Table view. Will you please help me. here is my code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NamazTime.h"
#import <Foundation/NSXMLParser.h>
#import "NamazTimeController.h"

@protocol NSXMLParserDelegate;


@interface NamazTimeController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

    NSMutableArray *colorNames;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *colorNames;
- (void)loadNamTime;

@end




//
//  NamazTimeController.m
//  MCVNamaz
//
//  Created by Andy on 28/03/2011.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NamazTimeController.h"
#import "WSNamaz.h"
#import "NamazTime.h"

@implementation NamazTimeController
@synthesize colorNames;



- (void)dealloc {
    [colorNames release];
    [super dealloc];
}

//NamazTime *namTime = [[NamazTime alloc] init];



- (id)init {
    //Call the superclass's designated initializer
    [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //Get the tab bar item
    UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
    //Give it a label
    [tbi setTitle: @"Today"];
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Time.png"];
    [tbi setImage:i];


//  [arrWeek removeAllObjects];

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
*/


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    

    NSLog(@"view will appear works!!!!!");


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source
/*
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
//    return <#number of sections#>;
}

*/

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.colorNames count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /*
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
    }
//  [[cell textLabel] setText:[arrWeek objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
     */
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    return cell;


}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"array view load called");
//  self.colorNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"colorNames", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
//  NamazTime *nt = [[NamazTime alloc] init];
//  self.colorNames = [nt loadNamTime];

//  WSNamaz *wsnamaz = [[WSNamaz alloc] init];
//  self.colorNames = wsnamaz ver
//  [wsnamaz verifyXML];
    //NamazTimeController *ntcc = [[NamazTimeController alloc] init];
//  self.colorNames = wsnamaz.namazXmlArray;

    //self.colorNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:colorNames, nil];
    self.colorNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NamazTime *nt = [[NamazTime alloc] init];
    //self.colorNames = [nt loadNamTime];

    //NamazTimeController *wtcObject = [[NamazTimeController alloc] init];
    //[wsObject verifyXML];

    //self.colorNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //self.colorNames = [nt loadNamTime];
//  [wsnamaz verifyXML];
    //  displayText.text = @"text";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.colorNames = nil;

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)loadNamTime
{
    NamazTime *nt = [[NamazTime alloc] init];
    self.colorNames = [nt loadNamTime];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        NSLog (@"Element of color names  in the namaz time controller %i = %@", i, [colorNames objectAtIndex: i]);

    //[[self tableView] reloadData];
    [self viewDidLoad];


}   


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of issues here. Hope this will help you at least get your app running:

1. General comment to get better responses on stackoverflow: clean up your code, only paste parts relevant to the question you are asking, and format it correctly. The sample wasn't formatted as a code block and contains so many commented out sections you're making it hard for us to help.
2. `init` is not correctly initializing the instance. First, you need to use `self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`. Second, I would wrap everything else before `return self` in `if (self) {}` so it only executes if the initialization was successful.
3. Also in `init`, views are not loaded in `initXXX` methods so you should remove `[[self tableView] reloadData]`.
4. In `viewWillAppear` you are calling the `[super viewWillAppear]` twice. Probably isn't harmful but definitely not necessary. Since you do nothing in this method, I'd remove it completely in any case.
5. With regard to loading data into the table, you don't need to call `reloadData` the first time the view is loaded b/c the tableView will load itself the first time it is displayed. You do need to call `[tableView reloadData]` whenever data model changes warrant it. In your case you need attempt to do this in `loadNamTime`. You should not call `[self viewDidLoad]` as that is incorrect and can have unwanted side effects. Generally, you should never manually call `viewDidLoad`, this is a system message based on the view actually being loaded. Uncomment the line `[[self tableView] reloadData]`.

Comment: Hi I have placed one tableview query. Can you check and answer this one also on following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239543/tableview-is-not-showing-data